# Add a value list for specific keys in dictionary (python 3.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to return a dictionary with capital letter as keys and a list small letters as values.

```
def sample(d):
    new_group = {}
    for small_letters, capitals in d.items():
        for capital in capitals:            
            new_group[capital] = [small_letters]
    return(new_group)

print(sample({"aaa":["A","B"], "bbb":["A","C"], "ccc":["A"]}))
```

My code returns:

```
{"A":["ccc"], "B":["aaa"], "C":["bbb"]}
```

Expected result:

```
{"A":["aaa","bbb","ccc"], "B":["aaa"], "C":["bbb"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-writing the dictionary value, not appending to the list.

```
def sample(d):
    new_group = {}
    for small_letters, capitals in d.items():
        for capital in capitals:            
            new_group[capital] = new_group.get(capital, []) + [small_letters]
    return(new_group)

print(sample({"aaa":["A","B"], "bbb":["A","C"], "ccc":["A"]}))
```

Results:

```
{'A': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], 'B': ['aaa'], 'C': ['bbb']}
```

Comment: Thanks Larry, that's my huge problem, instead of adding the element to list, my code overwrites the existing element. This is the use of get() method. Again thanks, this gives me headache for a couple of hours.